# All my Orchard sites in IIS connect to the same database

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, orchardcms, iis-10

My Windows Server 2016 machine had a unexpected shutdown due to saturation of memory and after I open it again all my Orchard sites who were working fine went to setup page of Orchard and from what I understand none of them is reading the appsettings file, even deleted Appdata folder and the same page.

So I made a copy from one of my Orchard websites and created a test database (empty) and tried to do the setup and now all my Orchard websites point to the same database and none of them is working due to error in the making of one the tables in that database. So I deleted the database and same error in the event viewer, it says it cannot access to the database.

I stopped SQL Server and pointed my site to another remote SQL Server but it still points to local SQL Server and says it's not working. I tried Windows authentication, deleted all .NET core packages, SDK's runtime and reinstalled them, but there is the same problem.

Can anyone have a idea on what's wrong with my IIS please?

Comment: If you create an empty asp.net core application without using orchard, and deploy it to IIS, could it connect to database? IIS hasa connection string module, you can check connection string in it.

Comment: Yes my others asp.net core applications they are working fine and they connect to the right database. The problem is only for orchard